# Azure devops release pipeline creation using terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, cicd

I have to create release pipeline in azure devops using terraform. I am able to create build pipeline in azure devops using terraform but for release pipeline I am not getting any resource. Can anyone help me in this? Is there any way we can create release pipelines using terraform in azure devops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Terraform provider for Azure DevOps doesn't support release pipelines. There is a PR to add this functionality, but it's `WIP` and hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/microsoft/terraform-provider-azuredevops/pull/178

Comment: Okay Thank you for the update. I am looking for this resource only

Comment: Is there any other we can achieve this? Azure resources template or ARM template?

Comment: @SwapnilMahadik You could use [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) /[vsteam](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Add-VSTeamReleaseDefinition) PowerShell module, but they both need JSON definition that you have to export from existing release. The definition can be tweaked manually, but there is no formal spec for it AFAIK, so you're on your own.

Comment: Okay Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this instruction?
https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/

I know that terraform has two stages:
terraform plan & terraform apply

Seems to me you are missing the terraform apply stage which is covered quite nicely in Exercise 3

Comment: Yes but I want this to be create automatically when we run terraform apply command from our command line. The same way I am able to create build pipeline but not getting resource for release pipeline